# Hadoop 2.6 start-dfs.sh errors on Centos 6.7

Tags: server, hadoop

I use this [tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/#) to install Hadoop 2.6 on Centos 6.7 with Java 1.8.0_72 and everything goes well before execution of start-dfs.sh from Hadoop-home/sbin/srart-dfs.sh. Below is the output:

```
[hadoop@10 sbin]$  start-dfs.sh
16/02/26 21:47:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
0.0.0.0: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
0.0.0.0: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
16/02/26 21:47:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

It seems there is something wrong with /etv/bashrc @ line 65. But, I checked and there is nothing I modified.

I run CentOS 6.7 final releas using Parallel VM manager of my Mac which is a 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is Ubuntu Linux forum and we can't help with CentOS running in Virtualbox on your mac. BTW what's the content of /etc/bashrc

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the solution to your problem but it will point to something which can really help you out. At least it worked in my case without any issues.**
Few months back I wrote a blog about installing single node hadoop cluster in Ubuntu. You can refer to this [here](http://gettingstartedwithhadoop.blogspot.com/)

I made use of these two links for Hadoop1(MRv1)
[link1](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)
[link2](http://mysolvedproblem.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-on.html)

And this one for Hadoop2(MRv2)

[link3](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php)

Both the times  I have successful in terms of running them on my Ubuntu destkop machines. You can refer these links for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All for hints. I figured out that the problem appears when I start

> ssh localhost

then I realised that the PATH in /etc/environment is corrupted. The instruction given by the tutorial does not work for me without touch up. So, I added all the below required path before providing jdk path. The problem solved that easy but took 2 days for me to figure out.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_73/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_73/jre/bin
```

I hope others also get benefit of this Q&A.

Thanks